# Cannot get data from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have AppUser table inherit from IdentityUser table.

and I have DBContext inherit from IdentityDbContext to create all tables in one database

```
public class MyCustomDBContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{

    public MyCustomDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyCustomDBContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to select bookmarks for specific article like that code, **Username** is always **null** ?

```
from a in context.Bookmarks
where a.ArticleID == articleID
select new Bookmark
{
    UserID = a.UserID,
    BookmarkDate = a.BookmarkDate,
    appUser = new AppUser 
    { 
        UserName = a.appUser.UserName 
    }
}
```

I think that because AppUser table is come from the inherited context IdentityDbContext,

So, what can i do

if i try to define property for AppUser table in MyCustomDBContext like this, it will cause hide to the User table in the parent IdentityDbContext

```
public DbSet<AppUser> muUsers { get; set; }
```

Comment: You probably need a JOIN to join the user table with the current table.  There is probably a UserID and UserName so you need to cross reference the ID to the name.

Comment: Do not use 2 dbcontexts ! use only one!

Comment: i used join before not succeed,

Comment: I already use one dbcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my mistake,

I used ForeignKey attribute over UserID instead of AppUser:

```
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public string UserID { get; set; }
```

instead of:

```
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public AppUser appUser { get; set; }
```

i adjust it and it work fine